# Read file from stdin C with scanf

Tags: c, stdin

I can read file contents from `stdin` with `scanf("%s", &input)`.

How much space should I be allocating for the `input` string if I do not know how long the file will be?

Comment: strings take in a char*. Leave off the '&'. Look into using fgets instead of scanf. This will prevent a buffer overflow, but if really need be you can allocate a safe amount of characters to be read in say like scanf(%255s",input);

Comment: There is no telling honestly. Generally reading files with unknown structure with `scanf` is discouraged.

Comment: Recommend reading 1 line at a time and establishing a max line length like 1000 - a value at least 2x what you think you may need. Then using `fgets()`, your buffer size should be 1000 + 2 (or maybe +3). Code could be written to handle arbitrary long lines, but IMO, excessively long lines should be detected and treated as an error instead.

Comment: you can open the file for read, use fseek to get to the end of the file, use ftell to find the total lenght, in bytes, of the file, use fseek to return to the beginning of the file, then  malloc a suitable sized buffer, then perform the read operation(s)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `fgets` instead of `scanf`. `scanf` can cause overflow, but you can tell to `fgets` the maximum size you want to read. If you need `scanf` for the format scanning, you can still use `sscanf` after `fgets`.

```
char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should reverse the question. You allocate a buffer of a defined size and them limit the input, be it with `scanf` of `fgets`.

```
#define SIZE 256
char buf[SIZE];
fgets(buf, SIZE, stdin);
```

or

```
scanf("%255s", buf);
```

and then iterate reading.

The use of `fgets` instead of `scanf` depends if your input is line oriented or space separated. And ... RTFM ...

Comment: this line: char buf[SIZE]; will be one char too short, due to fgets will add a terminating '\0' to the end of the buffer, so the line should be: char buf[SIZE+1];

Comment: @user3629249 No, according to manpage *fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream*. Here at most 255 characters will be read and there will be a place for the terminating `\0`.